# Subselect with LINQ

Tags: linq

I want to do a subselect with LINQ

**What I have, but incorrect**

```
var diretores = from item in db.San_PropostaConversa
                join sc in db.San_Credenciada
                    on (item.Credenciada_Id) equals sc.Credenciada_Id
                join sp in db.San_Proposta
                    on (item.Proposta_Id) equals sp.Proposta_Id
                join si in db.San_Imovel
                    on (sp.Imovel_Id) equals si.Imovel_Id
                join su in db.San_Usuario
                    on (item.Usuario_Id) equals su.Usuario_Id
                where item.Proposta_Id == proposta
                orderby item.DataHora descending
                select new
                {
                    sc.Apelido,
                    su.NomeCompleto,
                    su.DescricaoCargo1,
                    item.Comentario,
                    item.DataHora,
                    sp.Imovel_Id,
                    CredenciadaCaptadora_Id = si.Credenciada_Id,
                    item.Credenciada_Id,
                    (from item2 in db.San_Usuario
                     where item2.Cargo_Id == 9
                        && item2.Excluido == 0
                        && item2.Credenciada_Id == item.Credenciada_Id
                     select item2.Email)
                };
```

In my `SELECT` statement, I want to recover an email column following some conditions that are specified in my `WHERE` clause.

**Error**

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must
>   be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access

Comment: And what is preventing you from doing that? Did you try anything?

Comment: The error message tells you: "Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access". This is the exact cause and solution right there for you.

Comment: @usr If the OP had understood the error message, he wouldn't have posted a question here. Your comments are not very constructive and quite mean.

Comment: @david.s Googling the message turns up a number of explanations. I think this question is not helpful as it does not add new information to the web. We have too many questions of the type "Neither did I read or Google the message". That results in a lot of wasted time (for both sides).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 problems in your linq expression:

1. You need to assign the result of the subquery to a member of the new anonymous type.
2. I think you only want to select 1 email with your subquery, so you need to use `Single()`/`SingleOrDefault()` or `First()`/`FirstOrDefault()`.

Try this:

```
var diretores = from item in db.San_PropostaConversa
                join sc in db.San_Credenciada
                    on item.Credenciada_Id equals sc.Credenciada_Id
                join sp in db.San_Proposta
                    on (item.Proposta_Id) equals sp.Proposta_Id
                join si in db.San_Imovel
                    on sp.Imovel_Id equals si.Imovel_Id
                join su in db.San_Usuario
                    on item.Usuario_Id equals su.Usuario_Id
                where item.Proposta_Id == proposta
                orderby item.DataHora descending
                select new
                {
                    Apelido = sc.Apelido,
                    NomeCompleto = su.NomeCompleto,
                    DescricaoCargo1 = su.DescricaoCargo1,
                    Comentario = item.Comentario,
                    DataHora = item.DataHora,
                    Imovel_Id = sp.Imovel_Id,
                    CredenciadaCaptadora_Id = si.Credenciada_Id,
                    Credenciada_Id = item.Credenciada_Id,
                    Email = (from item2 in db.San_Usuario
                             where item2.Cargo_Id == 9
                                && item2.Excluido == 0
                                && item2.Credenciada_Id == item.Credenciada_Id
                             select item2.Email).FirstOrDefault()
                };
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly this error occurring for unavailable assigning variable,
please try this 
it will help you

```
var diretores = from item in db.San_PropostaConversa
                        join sc in db.San_Credenciada
                        on (item.Credenciada_Id) equals sc.Credenciada_Id
                        join sp in db.San_Proposta
                        on (item.Proposta_Id) equals sp.Proposta_Id
                        join si in db.San_Imovel
                        on (sp.Imovel_Id) equals si.Imovel_Id
                        join su in db.San_Usuario
                        on (item.Usuario_Id) equals su.Usuario_Id
                        where item.Proposta_Id == proposta
                        orderby item.DataHora descending
                        select new
                        {
                        Apelido=sc.Apelido,
                        NomeCompleto=su.NomeCompleto,
                        DescricaoCargo1=su.DescricaoCargo1,
                        Comentario=item.Comentario,
                        DataHora=item.DataHora,
                        Imovel_Id=sp.Imovel_Id,
                            CredenciadaCaptadora_Id = si.Credenciada_Id,
                        Credenciada_Id= item.Credenciada_Id,
                          result=  (from item2 in db.San_Usuario
                                 where item2.Cargo_Id == 9
                                 && item2.Excluido == 0
                                 && item2.Credenciada_Id == item.Credenciada_Id
                                 select item2.Email)
                        };
```